# Link Doesnt Click Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown

Not sure why this is happening, but if you click on my link the images from the top will slide down and if you click on one of those images they will slide back up. This works exactly how I want it to. However, when you go back and click on the link again it doesnt activate the slide down on the first click. It takes two clicks. I would like it to take only one click.

http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/Qr4AX/

Does anyone know why this occurs and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You have asked 12 questions and found no satisfactory answer?

Comment: Im new to this site and didnt realize how to mark a question as answered. Ive gone back and answered the ones that were really answered. This is a great site. Ive got more help here than from anywhere. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FzqfZ/

Comment: That seemed to have fixed the problem, but it changed the way the images slide down when I add other links. If you click one link after another they seem to slidedown on top of each other http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/FzqfZ/1/ I need them to completely slide up before the next set of images closes. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/FzqfZ/2/ I cant seem to fix it. Any ideas?